# Can't get Minecraft server to work

Tags: software-installation, minecraft

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and then downloaded the Mojang Minecraft server software. When I follow the directions and come to the part where I enter the command

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to the directions you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

> You will need to type that out on the terminal.

- Go to the folder where you extracted the the bedrock-server.
- Right click and click on *Open terminal*.
- It will open a terminal window for you.
- Type in the command there, and there you go you have successfully started the server.

[Warning: Do not close the terminal to close the server, type "*stop*"
   to stop it.]

### OPTIONAL

Create a file with the following contents:-

```
#/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server
```

and save it as *start.sh*, then you can double click every time to run the server.

Comment: When I do what u said I get "bash: ./bedrock_server: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @AndrewJensen what is your CPU Architecture? 32bit, 64bit, ARM etc.

Comment: @AndrewJensen Unfortunately for now the server is for x86 processors only and will not work on ARM processors. [More info](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/BDS-53?focusedCommentId=488989&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-488989)

Comment: Are there any reliable 32 bit Minecraft servers that I could install and run?

Comment: @AndrewJensen There is always a way, though they might be too time consuming or slow.
You might try using Qemu or Wine, both of which are processor emulator, and allows us to emulate the x86 instruction set. and both will be very slow (and buggy).
or You may consider paying for Realms :( 
or wait and [upvote](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360022601432-Dedicated-Servers-for-ARM-Devices).

There might be ways to run the APK directly on ARM, though i have no no idea how to do it. (Maybe using the Google App Runtime for Chrome).